# Databases in winforms c#

Tags: c#, database, winforms, entity-framework

I can't understand how to manage database with Entity Framework.

I'll try to describe my problem step-by-step

1. create winforms application
2. add database (.mdf) to solution
3. when appears window "choosing database model", select dataset
4. then finish, as database is empty
5. go to server explorer, choose created database, create some tables
6. add to solution EDM ADO.NET

The problem is that new data doesn't appear in my database in server explorer. This means that while my Winforms app is working, I can modify my database (change existing values, add new, ..). but if I close my app, there is no update in my database in server explorer. I DON'T forget to use function SaveChanges()

P.S. while my app is working, values are updating. Think, that means that data updates in dataset, but not in database. if i am right, give a clue how to update database from dataset.

pps. visual studio 2010 ultimate. sorry for english

```
dbentity db=new dbentity();
db.items.addobject(new item() {value=something});
db.savechanges();
```

Comment: there seems to be something missing.. how are you using the Entity when there is no apparent DataContext or anything like that for example.. what type is dbentity please paste all relevant code..

Comment: r u using tableadapter and dataset with entity framework....

Comment: @DJKRAZE when you add entity data model (edm) to your solution, there is an option to save parametres of connection edm with your database. it will be saved in App.Config.

Comment: I was not aware I've used entity framework differently sorry

Comment: First of all: can you show us your **connection string**?? I suspect you're using a *user instance* of SQL Server which would explain the bevavior. Also: if you're using Entity Framework - why on earth are you using `DataSets`, too? The whole point of EF is that you get back **real nice .NET objects** from your database and you **don't** have to use the clumsy old data sets.....

Comment: Removed the dataset tag, which was most likely there in error

Answer (score 1):

Don't add the database to your solution. You can [use the Server Explorer to add a connection to your database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms239722.aspx) via your existing SQL Server, or you can select your database in the [wizard that appears when adding a new EDMX file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399247.aspx) to your solution.

Did you try either of these? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: can you please describe step-by-step creating database in server explorer & connectionit with my solution?

Comment: @AliaksandrKroshner I've added a couple links. 
Remember that Google is your friend.